# How to call Azure Actions in xamarin forms using Azure Service Provider

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Service provider (Azure SDK in xamarin forms) to download data from Azure cloud Server, I am using bellow code to fetch all data

```
 var table = AzureServiceProvider.Instance.GetRemoteTable<T>();

var query = table.CreateQuery();
            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = table.Where(filter);
            }
            List<T> azureDatas;
            await query.ToListAsync();
```

when I use code above it hits following URL https://MyService.azurewebsites.net/tables/TableName

But now I have to pass id (i.e api/table/{TableName}/{controller}/{id}) to fetch only required data for matching that that id

using above same code its hitting above URL
https://MyService.azurewebsites.net/tables/TableName 
Inst ed of that I want to use

EX:-
https://mobilddevservice.azurewebsites.net/tables/TableName/(methodName)/(ID)10338654

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you figures this out yet, but to target a specific method in your controller you can use the ".WithParameters" method on your table.

So lets say you have 2 methods in your controller:

```
// GET tables/TableName/id
public SingleResult<TableName> GetDataFromName(string name)
{
     //Your logic here
}

// GET tables/TableName/id
public SingleResult<TableName> GetDataFromAddress(string address)
{
    //Your logic here
}
```

You can access these methods individually by using the *.WithParameters* like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("name", name);        

var query = Table.WithParameters(parameters);                

var results = await query.ToEnumerableAsync();
```

To access the address method

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("address", personsAddress);        

var query = Table.WithParameters(parameters);                

var results = await query.ToEnumerableAsync();
```

So the important part is:

1. As far as I'm aware you can only send strings. But I might be
   wrong
2. The name in the parameters dictionary has to be the exact
   name of the variable in your controller!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for a lookup by Id:

```
var table = client.GetTable<T>();
var record = await table.LookupAsync(id);
```

It uses the different endpoint - `https://site.azurewebsites.net/tables/Table/{id}`.

For more info, check the book: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/

Comment: This will work for to get table data that I have already implemented. Now problem is that in azure API is like [link](https://mobilddevservice.azurewebsites.net/tables/TableName/getdata fromID/10338654) which i have various type of method in one controller   so how to target a particular method.

Comment: each method are like gatafromDate, getDatafromName for this need to pass different type of parameters. like long, datetime, string etc.

Comment: Your follow-on questions are not clear.  I don't understand what problem you are experiencing.

Comment: we have this kind of api how can use this in xamarin  [https://mobildvservice.azurewebsites.net/tables/ActionItem/GetUserActionItem/10338654](https://mobildvservice.azurewebsites.net/tables/ActionItem/GetUserActionItem/10338654)

Comment: You need a completely custom client SDK - you can't use the mobile apps SDK with random APIs - it's a combined server + client deployment.